# No result defined for action actions.AddExam and result input

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-jquery

I'm inputting some Data that i want to add to a database. I'm doing it through a form like this:

```
<s:form theme="simple" action="addExam">
                <div id="reg">
                    <s:textfield name="exam.name" cssErrorClass="register error"
                        placeholder="Exam Name" cssClass="register" required="" />
                    <s:textfield name="exam.minutesAllotted"
                        placeholder="Minutes Allotted" cssClass="register" required="" />
                    <s:textfield name="exam.numQuestions"
                        placeholder="Number Of Questions" cssClass="register" required="" />
                    <sj:datepicker name="exam.startDate" cssClass="register"
                        placeholder="Start Date" displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" required="" />
                    <sj:datepicker name="exam.endDate" cssClass="register"
                        placeholder="End Date" displayFormat="dd/mm/yy" required="" />
                </div>
                <!-- Blue Button -->
                <s:submit type="button" cssClass="button blue" value="Add" />
            </s:form>
```

Relevant portion of struts.xml:

```
<action name="addExam" class="actions.AddExam">
            <result name="success" type="chain">display-exams</result>
            <result name="error">/add_exam.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

And my action is as follows:

```
public class AddExam extends ActionSupport{
    //Has getter and setter with proper naming convention
    private Exam exam;



    @Override
    public String execute()
    {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ExamModulePu");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        ExamService service = new ExamServiceImplementation(em);
        Exam examResult = service.createExam(exam);

        String result;
        if(examResult==null)
        {
            addFieldError("exam.name", "Duplicate Exam Name");
            result = SUCCESS;
        }
        else
            result = ERROR;

        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return result;
    }
```

My exam entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Exam implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
    private int numQuestions;
    private int minutesAllotted;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exam", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Question> questionList;
}
```

**When i input data into this form i get an error "No result defined for action actions.AddExam and result input" with a stacktrace:**

```
No result defined for action actions.AddExam and result input

    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:546)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I *think* it has something to do with the date input not being processed correctly and being set into my exam data member. I can pick a date from the drop down and select it but even if i input an invalid date such as 23/11/51325 it still allows me to submit and gives me the same error. Maybe it's a mismatch of format between my Date variable and the input?

Comment: startDate and endDate are java.util.Date ? Or some other stuff like java.sql.Date ? You should post the request taken with Firebug NET module too

Comment: And since you are chaining to another Action, that action configuration is relevant too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result `input` is triggered when some validation over the form is not correct. You must add that result into your mapped `action` tag over `struts.xml`:

```
<action name="addExam" class="actions.AddExam">
    <result name="success" type="chain">display-exams</result>
    <result name="error">/add_exam.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/add_exam.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Doing that maybe you don't need that `<result name="error">`.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the validation error could be? That in itself is a bug because i get this result even when all the data inputted is valid..

Comment: @VinayBangaloreNagaraj No, but if you add what I suggest the error should appear in your form, and therefore you will be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define **display-exams** action name and mapping in your struts.xml file.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: <result name="success" type="chain">display-exams</result>

Comment: <action name="display-exams" class="actions.DisplayExam">
    <result name="success">/display-exams.jsp</result>
</action>

Comment: Add your impl in the action class method

Comment: plz refer it this example

Comment: Please update your answer to contain additional info mentioned in the comments. Thank you.